# removeClass on dynamically added class is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a `div` which I want to show when specific `radio` options are selected. This `div` resides in a `form` and if a guest, who is a toddler, is attending (by specifying "yes" in the radio options") then this hidden div (`guest__cot`) should appear. Idea being is that I only want to showcase cot options if a toddler is attending.

I have got the `div` appearing successfully. However, if I then select no from the radio option, the div still remains visible (doesn't `removeClass`).

Steps to reproduce, in the demo:

1. Select "yes" for "Name 1 (Toddler)"
2. [`.guest__cot` div appears]
3. Now, for "Name 1 (Toddler)" select "no", the div still remains visible (`$(".guest__cot").removeClass("guest__cot--visible");` isn't executing)

I essentially want to showcase `.guest__cot` if any toddler has "yes" selected, and to hide it if otherwise.

Demo:

```js
(function($) {

  $(".member__attendance-input.is_toddler").on('change', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var attendance_value = $this.val();
    var showCotField = "show-cot-field";

    if (attendance_value === "yes") {
      $this.addClass(showCotField);
    } else if ((attendance_value === "no")) {
      $this.removeClass(showCotField);
    }

    if ($('.member__attendance-input').hasClass(showCotField)) {
      $(".guest__cot").addClass("guest__cot--visible");
    } else {
      $(".guest__cot").removeClass("guest__cot--visible");
    }

  });


})(jQuery);
```

```css
.rsvp {
  padding: 60px 0;
}

form {
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.input-label {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.member {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.member__name {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.member__options {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.guest__cot{
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.guest__cot--visible {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="rsvp">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <form>

          <!-- member 1 -->
          <div class="member d-flex flex-column">
            <span class="member__name">Name 1 (Toddler)</span>
            <div class="member__attendance member__options d-flex">
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input is_toddler" id="attending-yes-0" type="radio" name="attending-0" value="yes" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-yes-0">Yes</label>
              </div>
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input is_toddler" id="attending-no-0" type="radio" name="attending-0" value="no" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-no-0">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- member 2 -->
          <div class="member d-flex flex-column">
            <span class="member__name">Name 2 (Toddler)</span>
            <div class="member__attendance member__options d-flex">
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input is_toddler" id="attending-yes-1" type="radio" name="attending-1" value="yes" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-yes-1">Yes</label>
              </div>
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input is_toddler" id="attending-no-1" type="radio" name="attending-1" value="no" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-no-1">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- member 3 -->
          <div class="member d-flex flex-column">
            <span class="member__name">Name 3 (Adult)</span>
            <div class="member__attendance member__options d-flex">
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input" id="attending-yes-2" type="radio" name="attending-2" value="yes" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-yes-2">Yes</label>
              </div>
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input" id="attending-no-2" type="radio" name="attending-2" value="no" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-no-2">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="guest__cot">
            Show this div if either toddler options are "yes"
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pointy - Sorry, that was my mistake. That was just me testing locally, have updated q with correct classes.

Comment: You add that class to the radio button inputs via the jQuery `this`, but each radio button is two separate inputs. Then you check `$('.member__attendance-input')` to see if it has the marker class, but that will only get you the result from the first such input on the page. Basically the logic is very much incorrect. You have to check if *any* of the radio buttons are set to "yes", so the "yes" buttons need to have their own class, and you need to check all of them.

Comment: @Pointy - I may be misreading / missing something from you above message, but the inputs are differentiated by the `is_toddler` class that is assigned to them? On input change of any `.member__attendance-input.is_toddler` inputs, add the class if attendance is "yes". Then, check if any `input` has the class assigned to var `showCotField`

Comment: That's not how `.hasClass()` works. It operates on the first matching element in the list.

Comment: When the radio buttons change, the value of `this` in the event handler will be **one** of the radio buttons. They're independent elements, so when you add a class to one of them, removing that class from the other only effects that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/), [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the values of the selected toddler inputs. Then you use [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
to check if any of the values is a 'yes'. Try this

```js
(function($) {
    var $toddlerInputs = $(".member__attendance-input.is_toddler").on('change', function() {
        var values = $toddlerInputs.filter(':checked').map((i, el) => el.value).get();

        if (values.includes('yes')) {
          $(".guest__cot").show();
        } else {
          $(".guest__cot").hide();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.rsvp {
  padding: 60px 0;
}

form {
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.input-label {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.member {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.member__name {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.member__options {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.guest__cot{
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="rsvp">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <form>

          <!-- member 1 -->
          <div class="member d-flex flex-column">
            <span class="member__name">Name 1 (Toddler)</span>
            <div class="member__attendance member__options d-flex">
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input is_toddler" id="attending-yes-0" type="radio" name="attending-0" value="yes" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-yes-0">Yes</label>
              </div>
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input is_toddler" id="attending-no-0" type="radio" name="attending-0" value="no" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-no-0">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- member 2 -->
          <div class="member d-flex flex-column">
            <span class="member__name">Name 2 (Toddler)</span>
            <div class="member__attendance member__options d-flex">
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input is_toddler" id="attending-yes-1" type="radio" name="attending-1" value="yes" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-yes-1">Yes</label>
              </div>
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input is_toddler" id="attending-no-1" type="radio" name="attending-1" value="no" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-no-1">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- member 3 -->
          <div class="member d-flex flex-column">
            <span class="member__name">Name 3 (Adult)</span>
            <div class="member__attendance member__options d-flex">
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input" id="attending-yes-2" type="radio" name="attending-2" value="yes" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-yes-2">Yes</label>
              </div>
              <div class="member__attendance-option">
                <input class="member__attendance-input" id="attending-no-2" type="radio" name="attending-2" value="no" required />
                <label class="input-label" for="attending-no-2">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="guest__cot">
            Show this div if either toddler options are "yes"
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```